# How To Make a Squared App Bar Button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am wondering how do we make an App Bar action button like the one in the picture. It seems that adding a background or wrapping a widget on an Icon will not achieve the look of the button in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: You could use an OrientationBuilder to achieve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a demo of what you are trying to achieve:

```dart
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        title: Text(
          'Title',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          // squared button/icon
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 35,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
  body: .... YOUR WIDGETS ...
```

RESULT:

[image: result]

Comment: Great answer, but this code wont have a square icon when displayed on different screen sizes or will it?

Comment: The screen size doesn't matter here, the `AppBar`'s height doesn't change according to screen sizes so that won't be a problem @JayVDiyk

Comment: the AppBar height changes depending on platforms and pixel density, but thanks a lot for providing a detailed answer like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Icon` inside a `Container` with equal `width` and `heigth` (so you obtain a square), then you can round it with `BorderRadius` to obtain that effect.

Of course you should use the color property of the Container to fill the background.